# Use variable language specific strings in hugo config file

Tags: hugo, toml

My goal is to build a multilingual site using [hugo](https://gohugo.io/). For this I would like to:

- not touch the theme file
- have a config file which defines the overall structure for all languages (config.toml)
- have a "string" file for all languages

So for example, I would have a config.toml file like this:

```
[params.navigation]
    brand = "out-website"

    [params.navigation.links]
        about     = $ABOUT_NAME
        services  = $SERVICES_NAME
        team      = $TEAM_NAME
        impressum = $IMPRESSUM_NAME
```

a english language file:

```
ABOUT_NAME=About
SERVICES_NAME=Services
TEAM_NAME=Team
IMPRESSUM_NAME=Impressum
```

and a german language file like this:

```
ABOUT_NAME=Über uns
SERVICES_NAME=Dienste
TEAM_NAME=Mitarbeiter
IMPRESSUM_NAME=Impressum
```

And then I want to compile the project for english, I do something along  the line of:

```
hugo --theme=... --config=config.toml --config=english.toml
```

and german:

```
hugo --theme=... --config=config.toml --config=german.toml
```

Or in same similar way.

For this I need to use variables in the config.toml that are defined in english.toml or german.toml

My google search so far say, that I cannot use variables in toml.
So is there a different approach with which I could achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach with variables is not optimal, use the tutorial below.

Multilingual sites are coming as a feature on Hugo 0.16, but I managed to build a multilingual site on current Hugo using [this](http://gohugo.io/tutorials/create-a-multilingual-site/) tutorial and some hacks.

The tutorial above requires to "have a separate domain name for each language". I managed to bypass that and to have to sites, one at root (EN), and one in the folder (/LT/).

Here are the steps I used.

1. Set up reliable build runner, you can use Grunt/Gulp, but I used npm scripts. I hacked [npm-build-boilerplate](https://github.com/damonbauer/npm-build-boilerplate) and outsourced rendering from Hugo. Hugo is used only to generate files. **This is important**, because 1) we will be generating two sites; 2) hacks will require operations on folders, what is easy on npm (I'm not proficient on building custom Grunt/Gulp scripts).
2. Set up config_en.toml and config_de.toml in root folder as per tutorial.

Here's excerpt from my config_en.toml:

```
contentdir = "content/en"
publishdir = "public"
```

Here's excerpt from my config_lt.toml (change it to DE in your case):

```
contentdir = "content/lt"
publishdir = "public/lt"
```

Basically, I want my `website.com` to show EN version, and `website.com/lt/` to show LT version. This deviates from tutorial and will require hacks.

3. Set up translations in `/data` folder as per tutorial.
4. Bonus: set up snippet on Dash:

   {{ ( index $.Site.Data.translations $.Site.Params.locale ).@cursor }}

Whenever I type "trn", I get the above, what's left is to paste the key from translations file and I get the value in correct language.

5. Hack part. The blog *posts* will work fine on `/lt/`, but not static pages (*landing pages*). I use [this](https://discuss.gohugo.io/t/creating-static-content-that-uses-partials/265/17) instruction.

Basically, every static page, for example `content/lt/duk.md` will have slug set:

```
slug: "lt/duk"
```

But this slug will result in *double* URL path, for example `lt/lt/duk`.

I restore this using my npm scripts task using `rsync` and manual command to delete redundant folder:

```
"restorefolders": "rsync -a public/lt/lt/ public/lt/ && rm -rf public/lt/lt/",
```